# Excel VBA - add zero's inbetween two values

Tags: excel, vba

I've done quite a bit of searching around for this one...and I'm not getting anywhere.

I have a spreadsheet(specific column) with values such as:

```
42153-95    
54126-3    
13613-6331    
16136-336
```

My goal is to add zero's after the - and before the existing #'s(to 4 places).  Like:

```
42153-0095    
54126-0003    
13613-6331    
16136-0336
```

I've tried a a lot of different options within the quotes of NumberFormat:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C"). _ NumberFormat = "00000-0000"
```

No luck so far.  :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this have to be VBA? You can do this with a formula: `=LEFT(A1,6)&TEXT(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),"0000")` and then just copy -> paste special -> values

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub testFunc()

    MsgBox addZero("54126-3")

End Sub
```

'/ Function to add Zeros

```
Public Function addZero(strVal As String) As String

    Dim arrTemp
    Dim strTemp

    arrTemp = Split(strVal, "-")

    strTemp = arrTemp(0) & "-" & String(4 - Len(arrTemp(1)), "0") & arrTemp(1)

    addZero = strTemp

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

As @tigeravatar stated it can be done with a formula.  With the Evaluate function we can use an array form of the formula he gave in his comment.

You can apply this to your values in column C:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C4").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=INDEX(LEFT(C1:C4,6) & TEXT(--MID(C1:C4,7,LEN(C1:C4)),""0000""),)")
```

If your range is dynamic and you have the final row in a variable like `lstrow` you can replace all the `C4` with `C" & lstrow & "`

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & lstrow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=INDEX(LEFT(C1:C" & lstrow & ",6) & TEXT(--MID(C1:C" & lstrow & ",7,LEN(C1:C" & lstrow & ")),""0000""),)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to process and run:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range

    bry = Array("0000", "000", "00", "0", "")
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Value, "-")
        ary(1) = bry(Len(ary(1))) & ary(1)
        r.Value = Join(ary, "-")
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: I'm liking your solution the best so far, however it is blowing up pretty commonly.  It seems to work half the time...then continuously dies on this line:         ary(1) = bry(Len(ary(1))) & ary(1)                                                                                                       Interestingly enough, when it blows up, if I click stop debugging, and try again it will work momentarily, then have the same error shortly after.

Comment: Data must have the dash and zero to four characters after

Comment: Blew up on the 544117-30 porttion of this data:                                                                                                                454117-0120
454117-0070
454117-0040
454117-0020
454117-30
454107-010
454117-080
454107-020
454868-020
454868-050

Comment: All in cells in the same Column.  It did the first 4 successfully, stopped on the 5th